# How to delete a client from whmcs by php script from other service?

Tags: whmcs

Can anyone help to give a idea on how to delete a client from whmcs by php script from other service? Is there any way?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

PHP script:

```
$postfields["action"] = "deleteclient";
$postfields["clientid"] = "1";
```

This is done using the external WHMCS API. More information [here](http://docs.whmcs.com/API%3aDelete_Client).